# How to change the preview window style in VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-7, visual-studio-2013

Im currently developing a piece of software, however ive run into a minor problem with VS2013.

In the form designer, while I am designing the windows have a Win8 style window theme like this:

[image]

However when i actually run the program, the it uses a Win7 style window theme like this:

[image]

The change of border size kind of messes with my layouts and i was wondering if there was any way to make VS2013 preview with a win7 theme?

Comment: The problem is you use Visual Studio 2013 in Windows 7. The interface is only supported in Windows 8.

Comment: @Leonel Oh ok. So would it be better to switch to 2010, or doesn't really matter? Its interesting that the buttons are still Win7 styled, rather than metro styled.

Comment: It's depends on your OS Style.